# In Room drop an Entity and recreate with updated changes

Tags: android, sql, performance, sqlite, android-room

I'm using Room database in my application. I've some changes in columns of the Entity , so in DB Migration I want to drop the old table and recreate it with the updated Entity. But after Drop Table query instead of writing a long query to create the table again, can we just pass the entity model somehow or tell the DB to recreate the entity? Because my Entity has a number of columns,relations and onDelete rule in it so query would be complex.

Following is the Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = MediaTags.TABLE_NAME_UPLOAD_MEDIA,
        foreignKeys =
        @ForeignKey(
                entity = PostUpload.class,
                parentColumns = PostTags.COLUMN_UPLOAD_POST_LOCAL_ID,
                childColumns = MediaTags.COLUMN_UPLOAD_MEDIA_POST_ID,
                onDelete = CASCADE),
        indices = {@Index(MediaTags.COLUMN_UPLOAD_MEDIA_POST_ID)})
public class MediaUpload {
    @Ignore
    public final static int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    @Ignore
    public final static int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = MediaTags.COLUMN_UPLOAD_MEDIA_KEY)
    public String mediaKey; // unique key
    @ColumnInfo(name = MediaTags.COLUMN_UPLOAD_MEDIA_HASH_MD5)
    public String hashMd5;   // hashMd5 of file, for now we are sending it empty, in future will be used
    @ColumnInfo(name = MediaTags.COLUMN_UPLOAD_MEDIA_TYPE)
    public int mediaType;  // picture or video
    @ColumnInfo(name = MediaTags.COLUMN_UPLOAD_MEDIA_STATUS)
    public int status = UploadStatus.NOT_COMPRESSED; // upload and edit statues
    @ColumnInfo(name = MediaTags.COLUMN_UPLOAD_MEDIA_FILE_PATH)
    public String filePath;
    @ColumnInfo(name = MediaTags.COLUMN_UPLOAD_MEDIA_POST_ID)
    public String postId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = MediaTags.COLUMN_UPLOAD_MEDIA_THUMBNAIL)
    public String thumbnail;  // thumbnail in case of videos
    @ColumnInfo(name = MediaTags.COLUMN_UPLOAD_MEDIA_OVERLAY_PATH)
    public String overlayPath;  // overlay image containing all the editing

}
```

Comment: Please, be more specific. Do you want to add new columns to an existing table? Sharing your Room Database class will help...

Comment: I want to create a new column and delete an existing column

Comment: ok, please, share your `RoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context)` method

Comment: So basically you don't want to use Migration commands because you have to write a lot ?

Comment: Just drop the table and re-create.

Comment: yes, i don't want to write until it is the last option. May be we can tell Room to create the entity as it does for the very first time when it create database.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could use the following :-

```
private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override

    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            //Create the new table BUT with a different name
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_mediatags;"); -- just in case but not really required
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE new_mediatags (the_column_definitions_you_want)");
            //Copy existing data into the new table (if required)
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO new_mediatags SELECT the_columns_you_are keeping,null;");
            //Rename the original table
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE mediatags RENAME TO old_mediatags;");
            //Rename the new table to the original name
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE new_mediatags RENAME TO mediatags;");
            //Drop the renamed original table
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS old_mediatags;");
    }
};
```

- This assumes that you want to keep the existing data, if not then simply don't copy the data.

As an example consider the following :-

```
-- Create the original and load with some data
DROP TABLE If EXISTS mediatags;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mediatags (col1, col2, col3);
INSERT INTO mediatags VALUES('A','B','C'),('D','E','F');
SELECT * FROM mediatags;

-- The code that would be used
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_mediatags;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_mediatags (col1, col3, col4); -- note no col2 but new col added as col4
INSERT INTO new_mediatags SELECT col1,col3,null FROM mediatags; -- copy existing data 
ALTER TABLE mediatags RENAME TO old_mediatags;
ALTER TABLE new_mediatags RENAME TO mediatags;
DROP TABLE old_mediatags;


SELECT * FROM mediatags; -- output the data for the demo
```

The first 4 lines just create the original table, load it with some data and outpts the data as per :-

[image]

The other lines, swap the original table for the new table, removing col2 and adding col4, copying the existing data (the new column will be null although a value could be supplied) and finally for the demo outputs the data in the changed table as per :-

[image]

Comment: thanks, but does it mean that there is no way other than writing query and we can't tell Room to recreate the Entity itself.

Comment: @UsmanRana I don't believe so, as otherwise you get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle ItemEntry(aso.so56326640.ItemEntry).
     Expected:` and the Expected will mismatch the Found. That is the table after migration has to match the Entity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your previous version was 1 and now you want to update to version 2

```
   INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), RoomDatabase.class, databaseName).addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).build;
```

To add a column

```
private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // to delete a column
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE atable DROP COLUMN acolumn");
        // to add a new column
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE atable ADD COLUMN anewcolumn INTEGER NOT NULL default 0");
    }
};
```

Of course, you need to use your new column type, INTEGER, TEXT, etc.

The table contents will remain unchanged with a new column initialized with the default value.

Comment: I don't just want to add a column i want to delete another column too. and for that i have to recreate the table

Comment: DROP Column is not supported any other